# Trying to get a handle to all my runnings programms in c++ in Windows

Tags: c++

I'm trying to get a HWND of all my running programs. I only want to have HWND to  GUI´s visible on my desktop.

However, I still have a lot of other programs than those I opened in the vector. Does anyone know a solution to my problem?

```
BOOL IsUserWindow(HWND hwnd) {
    
    return IsWindowVisible(hwnd) && ((GetWindowLong(hwnd, GWL_EXSTYLE) & WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW) == 0);
}
```

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam) {


    std::vector<HWND>* windowHandles = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<HWND>*>(lParam);
    if (IsUserWindow(hwnd))
    {
        windowHandles->push_back(hwnd);
    }
    

    return TRUE; 
}
```

```
int main(){
    std::vector<HWND> windowHandles;
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&windowHandles));
}
```

Comment: That depends. What's your definition of programs "you opened"? If you opened a launcher executable and that executable immediately launched some other program and then exited, is that other program one that "you opened"? If a program was set to automatically start when you log in, is that one you opened? The difficulty here is determining the actual criteria, not (necessarily) in implementing it.

Comment: In the case of a launcher, if you run the launcher programmatically and leave the process handle open, then enum running processes and look at their parent PID, you can find child processes that the launcher runs. Alternatively, you can put the launcher process into a job object and then enum running processes checking if they belong to the same job

Comment: ok, I try to clarify the "programs I opened" a bit more.  I mean Only GUI´s visible on my desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply your own filtering in your `EnumWindowsProc`, as the `EnumWindows` function just gets a list of all the currently open Windows.

You could try using `GetForegroundWindow` and `GetNextWindow`, but I am not sure that would give you all the ones you want.